# PDF creation and download using Itext in rest end call and angular js

Tags: spring-mvc, itext7

This is the first time I'm using the library iText.  So need some clarifications, how can I configure Itext ibrary in my spring

Answer (score 0):

Start here to get it installed: [iText 7: Jump Start Tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/installing-itext-7)

The tutorials should get you started. If you have specific questions after that, come back here.  Using in Spring MVC is no more complicated than using it without it.  You just have to generate the PDF normally (maybe write to a ByteArrayOutputStream), and then serve the PDF as a resource with the right headers and stuff so that it downloads client-side.